# Set height of a map depending on screen size with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know that Twitter Bootstrap works really well horizontally on varying screensizes

However, how do can I set the height of an element in my page to be a specific height depending on the page/screen size?

I have a map which I need to take up different heights depending on the screen size

Paul

Comment: can use css media queries

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSS3 `Media Queries` to do this. For example you have a structure like this:

**CSS Styling:**

```css
/* This default styling works for large screen devices (All devices with resolution of 1200px or above), for example laptops */

#map > iframe{
  width: Your Value;
  height: Your Value;
}

/* This media query works for medium screen devices (All devices with resolution from 992px to 1199px), for example Computers */

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px){

  #map > iframe{
    width: Your Value;
    height: Your Value;
  }  
}

/* This media query works for small screen devices (All devices with resolution from 768px to 991px), for example tablets */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){
  #map > iframe{
    width: Your Value;
    height: Your Value;
  }
}

/* This media query works for extra small screen devices (All devices with below resolution of 767px), for example Iphones, Smart Phones */

@media (max-width: 767px){
  #map > iframe{
    width: Your Value;
    height: Your Value;
  }
}
```

**HTML Markup**

```html
<div id="map">
    <iframe src="Link to the google map" width="Some Value" height="Some Value">
        
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Just remove those `width` and `height` html attributes from the `<iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

I would set the heights using media queries i.e.

```
@media (min-width:320px) { /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ }
@media (min-width:481px) { /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */ }
@media (min-width:641px) { /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */ }
@media (min-width:961px) { /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1025px) { /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1281px) { /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ }
```

And changing the height in each media query

Answer (score 0):

Page or screen size are different things.

You may use `vh`in your media queries, if `vh` meets your compatibility [requirements](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units). In some cases you might want to set html, body and other elements' height to 100% or so, so that child element could inherit height from parent element. Otherwise setting height percentage doesn't work.

EDIT: if you know EXACT size of elements, just set them as height values in your media queries.